# Парсинг html, содержащей скрипт

Tags: c#

Цель - получить полный код некой страницы. Использую WebBrowser. После полной загрузки страницы в коде страницы обнаружил отсутствие ключевых элементов. Покопавшись в коде понял, что эти самые элементы формируются неким скриптом. Не нашёл при этом в коде страницы наименования функции. Подскажите, куда копать. Если открыть эту страницу в InternetExplorer и там открыть исходный код страницы - то же самое, нужная инфа скрыта где-то в недрах скриптов

Comment: Почему в WebBrowser скрипты не добавляют нужных элементов? Может быть, в устаревшей версии IE (по умолчанию для совместимости используется что-то вроде IE8, но вообще это поправимо) скрипты ломаются?

Comment: А то, что вы получили, и есть полный код. Контент имеет право вообще генерироваться на сервере. Никто ж не говорит, что веб-страница должна предоставлять данные в удобном для скрейперов виде.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь официальным API сайта. Если API нет, сайт не хочет, чтобы с него снимали информацию, и вы не имеете права это делать.

Answer (score 0):

"элементы формируются неким скриптом" - такое сейчас модно. Но к сожалению это делает невозможным ручной парсинг. Сайты которые формируют нужные данные скриптами практически нереально парсить моим любимым способом - скачать html и ковыряться в тексте.
Проще всего будет ковырять таким Макаром: грузим в WebBrowser, дожидаемся полной загрузки DOM, далее возможно понадобится подождать ещё секунду или две, и только тогда начинаем искать нужные элементы. Ведь скрипты же могут и подкачивать что-то с сайта.
Также не стоит забывать про версию эмуляции, гуглите FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION с указанием для какого языка, значения тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation 
Если  я не так понял с чем конкретно у вас возникли проблемы - уточняйте под ответом.